# How to Get 3 Records that have the Shortest Distance in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that is very big, containing 160K rows of the data. The columns are id, x, y, z, pl, bs and building.

For same (x,y,z), there are multiple rows (different value of bs and pl).

I am given a value P, so I want to get the 3 distinct (x,y,z) that have the  shortest sum distances (euclidean distance).

For example, (x',y',z') has 3 rows, with different pl1, pl2, pl3. So the sum of the distances = sqrt{(pl1 - P)^2 + (pl2 - P)^2 + (pl3 - P)^2}

So, is this possible to do it purely in **MySQL**?

**Edited**
P is a scalar value like column pl. basically (x,y,z) are 3-dimension points, but the distance is computed based on column pl. I want to know 3 distinct points (x,y,z) that have sum of shortest distance, which is computed via sum(pl-P)

What I want to achieve is something like the K Nearest Neighbor (KNN) algorithm, as described in this [link](https://helloacm.com/the-k-nearest-neighbor-algorithm-prediction-demonstration-by-mysql/).

To sum up, given a scalar value P, the task is to find the 3 rows (with different x,y,z) from the table that have the shortest sum of distances.
The distances are computed as Sqrt{(P-pl1)^2 + (P-pl2)^2 + ... (P-pln)^2}, there may be more than 1 rows for (x, y, z).

[image: SQL Table]

create table script (ADDED)

```
Create table #TEMP (
        ID INT,
        x float,
        y float,
        z float,
        pl float,
        bs int,
        building int
        )
insert into #TEMP 
values 
(2,1582.1,-863.5,1.5,154.9,1,-1)
,(3,1602.1,-883.5,1.5,154,1,-1)
,(4,1602.1,-863.5,1.5,154.4,1,-1)
,(5,1622.1,-883.5,1.5,153.4,1,-1)
,(6,1622.1,-863.5,1.5,153.8,1,-1)
,(7,1622.1,-743.5,1.5,154.9,1,-1)
,(8,1642.1,-883.5,1.5,153.1,1,-1)
,(9,1642.1,-863.5,1.5,153.2,1,-1)
,(10,1642.1,-763.5,1.5,154.5,1,-1)
,(11,1642.1,-743.5,1.5,154,1,-1)
```

Comment: I'm having a very hard time understanding your data set. At first I thought that columns `x`, `y`, and `z` described a point in 3-space, but later in the question it kind of sounds like for any distinct set of values `x`, `y`, and `z`, there will exist three records whose three `pl` values describe such a point. Which is true? Or is it something else entirely? Also, what is `P`? Is it a vector having three dimensions (e.g. `(P.x, P.y, P.z)`) as would seem natural, or is it a scalar acting as a shorthand for the point `(P, P, P)` as implied by your formula?

Comment: What if x, y, z does not have 3 rows?

Comment: P is a scalar value like column pl.  basically (x,y,z) are 3-dimension points, but the distance is computed based on column pl. I want to know 3 distinct points (x,y,z) that have sum of shortest distance, which is computed via sum(pl-P)

Comment: doesn't matter how many rows (x,y,z) has. The sum of distance = sum(P - pl)

Comment: Maybe you now what you want but that question is not explaining what you want.

Comment: re-edited to add more details...

Comment: Can we get an example of a P ? that would work with the data provided

Comment: e.g. 150  is good.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% if I understand correctly but this is my answer. Let me know if its close or if there is an obvious mistake.

```
drop table #temp
Create table #TEMP (
        ID INT,
        x float,
        y float,
        z float,
        pl float,
        bs int,
        building int
        )
insert into #TEMP 
values 
(2,1582.1,-863.5,1.5,154.9,1,-1)
,(3,1602.1,-883.5,1.5,154,1,-1)
,(4,1602.1,-863.5,1.5,154.4,1,-1)
,(5,1622.1,-883.5,1.5,153.4,1,-1)
,(6,1622.1,-863.5,1.5,153.8,1,-1)
,(7,1622.1,-743.5,1.5,154.9,1,-1)
,(8,1642.1,-883.5,1.5,153.1,1,-1)
,(9,1642.1,-863.5,1.5,153.2,1,-1)
,(10,1642.1,-763.5,1.5,154.5,1,-1)
,(11,1642.1,-743.5,1.5,154,1,-1)


DECLARE @P FLOAT = 150

Select x,y,z,SQRT(SUM(POWER(pl-@P,2.0))) 'Distance'

from #TEMP
group by x,y,z
order by 4
```

Comment: I admit i do not understand the math you are trying to use, but I believe the calculation will give you the distance based on distances = sqrt{(pl1 - P)^2 + (pl2 - P)^2 + (pl3 - P)^2} , and so the smalliest distance is simply order by distance, (smallest to largest) , could change to SELECT TOP 3 if you don't want the first 3

Comment: @SteakOverCooked realized i had the wrong requation, i had P-PL not PL-P

Comment: Thanks, i've re-edited the answer base on your suggestion.